# Where should I ask questions related to time keeping?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to find a Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions related to time keeping or calendars. E.g. how does the Mayan calendar work, or what is the logic behind the lunar calendar.

Does such a site exist? If so, which one is it?

Note that this question is not about programming using a calendar API or the Unix or Windows calendar. I'm curious about actual calendars used in different cultures and their logic and development.

Comment: Related:https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8843/what-would-a-lunar-calendar-look-like https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/lunar-calendar-accuracy-for-predicting-new-moons/16518

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no site in the network dedicated to calendars and related topics. But I don't think you need to worry:

- [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com) has quite a few question about [historic calendars](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) (74 while I'm writing this).
- [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) doesn't have a dedicated calendar tag but it does have [some questions about modern calendars](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=calendar).
- Several religious sites in the network have questions about their own calendar:

  - Christianity: [24 questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)
  - Judaism: [376 questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)
  - Islam: [80 questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=calendar)
  - Hinduism: [33 questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)

As always, please search before asking your question, and consult the Help Center (/help/on-topic) to know more about which type of questions can be asked on the site. And try to be specific: just asking "how does the Mayan calendar work" on History.SE is likely to be closed as too broad. You're better off reading the Wikipedia article and come back if you have a question about a single issue you don't understand.