# The number of questions and answers on my network profile is off by one

Tags: bug, network-profile

While I'm writing this question, I've written [301 questions and 1,324 answers](http://web.archive.org/web/20200101105820/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) on this site:

[image]

Yet my network profile shows [300 questions and 1,323 answers](http://web.archive.org/web/20200101105833/https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts):

[image]

I don't think it's a caching issue, as I've checked the profiles of users who posted something today and their counts have been properly updated. My [newest post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341334/295232) is ~30 hours old. Deleted posts might play a role, but my [last deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338611/295232) is from last November, and none of my questions has been Roomba'ed since. My [last deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341339/295232) is somewhat newer (24 hours).

---

After I posted this (my 302nd) question, the number of questions on my network profile had *immediately* increased by 1, to 301, so it *is* updated but it's still off by one.

A year later, the problem still persists, but I now noticed it also happens to my MathOverflow account; the network profile says 16 answers:

[image]

one more than my site profile (15 answers):

[image]